# How does trigger file in recovery.conf work?

Tags: postgresql, failover, master-slave-replication

Can someone explain how the `trigger_file` in `recovery.conf` works?

As far as I know the standby server will become the primary server when it detects the `trigger_file`. But how will the `trigger_file` be created when the primary server fails?

Comment: The trigger file is created by an external process/system that handles replication / fails / failovers, eg. manually. Example of tools that do this job: [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org/)

Comment: When does the external process you mentioned create a trigger file??@ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if you are joking. "How can I create a file?" Is that your question?

Comment: I was asking if the trigger_file is created when a primary server faces failover.

Comment: @SenthilVidhiyakar you are thinking the wrong way: when _you_ create the trigger file, will the failover happen, not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Any reliable failover scenario requires a third party, sometimes called a "witness", "arbitrator", "cluster monitor", "cluster manager" etc. to detect failure of one member and initiate a failover. This process ideally resides on a network separate from the one that connects cluster members to each other. It "pings" node(s) that are deemed to be masters or active nodes and triggers failover when they don't respond within the timeout threshold. In your case this monitor will create `trigger_file` to initiate the failover.

Comment: Thanks man..  Got it now.. But still I can't find a tutorial or demo for this..